# How to check if a result contains rows? (FbDataReader.HasRows always returns true!)

Tags: ado.net, firebird

I am using the Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider and before I pass the reader on to a consuming service I would like to determine whether any rows were returned. Consider the following snippet:

```
FbCommand cmd = GetSomeCommandFromTheEther();
FbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
    DoSomethingWith(reader);
else
    TellTheUserWeGotNothing();
```

What I've now learned is that `FbDataReader.HasRows` *always* returns True. In fact looking at [the source code](https://github.com/mono/old-code/blob/master/FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird/FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird/FbDataReader.cs) it would appear it is just a wrapper for `FbDataReader.command.IsSelectCommand`, not only useless, it makes the property name "HasRows" a complete misnomer.

In any event, how can I find out whether a given query has rows, *without advancing the record pointer*? Note that I want to pass the reader off to an external service; if I call `FbDataReader.Read()` to check its result, I will consume a row and `DoSomethingWith()` will not get this first row.

Comment: Could you file a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET ?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Seems like [there is one](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-305), closed as "Won't Fix".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am afraid you have stumbled on a `Firebird` limitation. As stated in following [Firebird FAQ link](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-net-provider-faq/#10):

> *Why FbDataReader.HasRows returns always true?*
>
> The FbDataReader.HasRows property is implemented for compatibility
>   only. It returns always true because Firebird doesn't have a way for
>   know if a query returns rows of not without fetching the data.

There is already a mention of this in the `Firebird Tracker`. Check the issue [DNET-305](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-305).

On the other hand, in .NET, it seems `OleDbDataReader` and `SqlDataReader`, which inherit from `DbDataReader` have the same problem, as stated in this [MSDN link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308352).

Since `FbDataReader` inherits from the same class as those, you might want to consider one of the workarounds that Microsoft suggests in its MSDN article, which is to perform first a `select count(*)`. Granted, that is unelegant and a waste of time and resources but at least it could help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and link. I've already used a workaround of just executing the same query twice: the first time, check the output of `Read()` and if it's true, go back and execute again. Honestly I don't like the explanation though (no fault of yours of course). Even if the server does not provide notification, why could they not simply read and cache the first row on the call to `HasRows`, then produce this row from a subsequent call to `Read()`. Or at the least, throw a NotSupportedException instead of lying to the callee.

Comment: I agree in that it should be done otherwise. Hopefully they will change it in future Firebird ADO.NET versions. Sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: No problem. I can only help the next person that comes along will find this answer first - before tearing their hair out debugging their (otherwise) error-free code. Especially when there's no IntelliSense documentation that mentions otherwise. :)